# Is the sentence correct? (about an e-book library system)

Tags: grammar, word-usage, sentence-construction, usage

I'm talking about an e-book library system.

Is the following sentence correct? Or how to make it better? Thank you for your help!

With(By?) the system, the school can set up what e-books are inappropriate for children to read, and then won’t be shown on the screen, so that students won’t get access to any of them.

Answer (score 1):

The proposed sentence can be understood, but it is not ideal.

A possible rewriting of the sentence gives:

> The system allows the school to specify which e-books are not suitable
> for children to read. These books will not be shown to the students,
> preventing access to them.

But I wonder whether that is the correct interpretation. Is "preventing" correct? Can clever students bypass the system? Would "hindering" be more accurate - but that word may confuse some people and lead to unwanted questions about "why not prevent" or "how to bypass".

Perhaps inverting the permission, as follows, works:

> The system allows the school to specify which e-books are suitable
> for the children. Students will only be shown these books on their screens.

Comment: These books will not be shown and students will be prevented from accessing them. :)

Comment: @Lambie That works. My preference would be to add one more word giving "... and so/thus/hence students ...".

Answer (score 1):

With(By?) the system, the school can set up what e-books are inappropriate for children to read, and then won’t be shown on the screen, so that students won’t get access to any of them.

English sentences are best when they are subject, verb and predicate.
Rewrite:

The system enables the school to flag books that are inappropriate for minors and therefore prevents students from seeing them or accessing them.